# MySQL: grouping by 2 columns to receive all values from 1st and 2nd columns

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

Primary table is:

| Date | Location | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jun, 1 | Location 1 | 1 |
| Jun, 2 | Location 2 | 1 |
| Jun, 3 | Location 1 | 1 |

In result of select statement I need to receive table like:

| Date | Location | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jun, 1 | Location 1 | 1 |
| Jun, 1 | Location 2 | 0 |
| Jun, 2 | Location 1 | 0 |
| Jun, 2 | Location 2 | 1 |
| Jun, 3 | Location 1 | 1 |
| Jun, 3 | Location 2 | 0 |

I'm wondering how I can get the above result.
In my case I can use only SELECT statement.

Thank you for your assist in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should have a location table and you need to left join it with this staging table to get this kind of result. Because, in this configuration you need to use cross join and it means much more load when you have more data than normal rate.

Here:

```
select distinct t1.datex, t1.location,
case
when t1.location = t2.location then t1.total
else 0 end as sum
from test t1 cross join test t2 order by 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=713591ab5611c9aef65a9895a5a560e9)